# Fail to run android project in virtual box emulator

Tags: android

*I am running project in virtualbox android emulator .*

My project working fine .but this time run project in virtual box android emulator .
give me following error in console window:

```
com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: I/O error
Launch canceled!
```

**Another project run  well** ,so many try and googling but i can't solve my problem .

Please help me ...

Answer (score 1):

Try complete uninstall, reinstalling the virualbox emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Android x86 at VirtualBox. It was caused by corrupted filesystem. Android was not able to remove application data, as well as i coudn't do that via the command line (had System I/O errors and FS corrupted messages).

I've tried to fix the filesystem using fsck directly from Android but without a luck. Then i've booted the virtual machine from the Linux LiveCD and fixed the Android filesystem. After that the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try Genymotion. It is quite fast.

[Genymotion Home Page](http://www.genymotion.com/)